# Query just one row that meet three conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'd like to make a query that returns just one row when it meets 3 conditions. I have a database that looks like this:

| Location | Date | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago | 2021-06-10 | 1 | 150 |
| New York | 2021-06-10 | 2 | 130 |
| Chicago | 2021-06-10 | 1 | 150 |
| Los Angeles | 2021-06-10 | 3 | 100 |
| Atlanta | 2021-06-10 | 4 | 120 |
| New York | 2021-06-09 | 2 | 125 |
| Chicago | 2021-06-09 | 1 | 155 |
| Los Angeles | 2021-06-09 | 3 | 99 |
| Atlanta | 2021-06-09 | 4 | 140 |

This database contains the price of different items, by date and location. This price changes each day and the price in each location for the same item does not need to be the same. Given that this database contains each sale made in a day, for each item, I'd like to make a query that returns only one observation by Location, Date and Item. I want to have like a time series for each the price of each item, in each location. So the resulting table should look like this:

| Location | Date | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago | 2021-06-10 | 1 | 150 |
| New York | 2021-06-10 | 2 | 130 |
| Los Angeles | 2021-06-10 | 3 | 100 |
| Atlanta | 2021-06-10 | 4 | 120 |
| New York | 2021-06-09 | 2 | 125 |
| Chicago | 2021-06-09 | 1 | 155 |
| Los Angeles | 2021-06-09 | 3 | 99 |
| Atlanta | 2021-06-09 | 4 | 140 |

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: have you looked into using DISTINCT?

Comment: It sounds like you just need `distinct` - what would you expect if *Chicago* had two different values for `item` or `price`?

Comment: The price in a day for a an Item and location does not change throughout the day. But there are a bunch of different items sold in a location. I have looked into distinct, but don't know how to insert 3 conditions into the distinct.

Comment: you don't specifiy "conditions", given your two rows for Chicago are duplicates, it will automatically return a single row as depicted in your example desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on the comments, this will give ***exactly*** what you have specified.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
```

The `DISTINCT` key word looks at ***all columns*** in each row and eliminates any row that exactly matches any other row.

If the `price` can vary within a day, but you want the maximum value, for example, use a `GROUP BY`...

```
SELECT
  location,
  date,
  item,
  MAX(price)  AS max_price
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  location,
  date,
  item
```

That will ensure you get one row per unique combination of `location, date, item`, and then you can pick which `price` to include using aggregate functions.

Note: Using keywords such as `date` as column names is a bad idea.  depending on your database you may need to "quote"/"escape" such column names, and even then the make reading the code harder for others.